# NServiceBus clustered workers / Distributor usage

Tags: nservicebus

[image: Current Setup]

**Current Setup**

We have a UI (well more than 1 UI, but that is not relevant), and we have 2 load balanced app servers. Such the UI will talk to an alias, behind which are the 2 load balancer app servers.
The app servers are also self hosting NServiceBus endpoints. The app server (this could be either App Server 1 or App Server 2 ) that is dealing with the current request is capable of doing the following using the self hosted NServiceBus:

- Send a message locally (this is a calculation that can be run at any
  time, and it doesn’t matter who triggers it, it is just a trigger to
  do the calculation)
- Send a command to the publisher on the Ancillary
  Service Box (the publisher pushes new event to Worker 1 and Worker 2)
- Send a command to Worker 1 directly on the Ancillary Services Box
- Send a command to Worker 2 directly on the Ancillary Services Box

**The "App Server(s)" current App.Config**

As such the App.Config for each app server has something like this

```html
  <UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      
      <add Assembly="Messages" Type="PublisherCommand" Endpoint="Publisher" />
      <add Assembly="Messages" Type=" Worker1Command" Endpoint="Worker1" />
      <add Assembly="Messages" Type=" Worker2Command" Endpoint="Worker2" />
      <!-- This one is sent locally only -->
      <add Assembly=" Messages" Type="RunCalculationCommand" Endpoint="Dealing" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

**The “Publisher” current  App.Config**

Currently the “Publisher” App.Config

```html
<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

**The “Worker(s)” current  App.Config**

Currently the worker App.Configs at the moment only have to subscribe to one other endpoint the “Publisher”, their config files looks like this:

```html
<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Assembly="Messages" Type="SomeEvent" Endpoint="Publisher" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

All other messages to the workers right now come directly from one of the app servers, as shown in the App.Config above for the app servers.

This is all working correctly.

Thing is we have a single point of failure, if the “Ancillary Services Box” dies, we are stuffed.

So we are wondering if we could make use of multiple “Ancillary Services Boxes (each with a Publishers/Worker1/Worker2)”. Ideally they would work exactly as described above, and as shown in the diagram above. Where if “Ancillary Services Box 1” is available it is used, otherwise we use “Ancillary Services Box 2”

I have read about the distributor (but not used it), which if I have it correct, we may be able to use in either the AppServer(s) themselves, where we treat each AppServer as a Distributor and a worker (for the case where we need to do the SendLocal command (RunCalculationCommand) we need to run).

Where the “Ancillary Services Box” would have to use the Distributor for each of the contained endpoints:

So we may end up with something like this:

[image: What we may want to do]

Could someone help me to know if I am even thinking about this the right way, or whether I am way off.

Essentially what I want to know is:

- Is the distributor the correct approach to use?
- What would the worker / publisher configs look like, they would have to change somehow to point to distributor no? As I state right now the app servers send a message directly to the workers, to the app server config has the worker end point address, and the worker is only setup to point to the publisher
- What would the app servers config look like? Would this stop sending directly to the publisher / workers?
- What would the publisher config look like? Should this point to the distributor?

Comment: Based on your message types it appears that the Handlers all have unique logic.  Is this actually the case?

Comment: Yeah they do, though for this question I obfuscated our true handler types. But in reality they are different/unique

Answer (score 5):

The distributor is a good approach here, but it comes at a cost of increased infrastructure complexity. To avoid introducing another single point of failure, the distributor and it's queues must be run on a Windows Failover Cluser. Meaning both MSMQ and DTC must be configured as clustered services. This can be oh so much fun.. :D

I've renamed what you call "worker" to endpoints, from Worker1 to Endpoint1 and Worker2 to Endpoint2. This is because "worker" is very clearly defined as something specific when you introduce the distributor. An actual physical endpoint on a machine that is receiving messages from a distributor is a worker. So Endpoint1@ServicesMachine01, Endpoint2@ServicesMachine02 etc. are all workers. Workers get work from the distributor.

### Scenario 01

[image: Command only scenario]

In the first scenario you see the app server gets a request from the load balancer and sends it to 
Endpoint1@Cluster01 or Endpoint2@Cluster01 queue on the distributor, depending on the command. The
distributor then finds a ready worker for message in that queue and send the command along to it. 
So for WorkerCommand1 EITHER Endpoint1@ServicesBox01 OR Endpoint1@ServicesBox02 ends up getting 
the command from the distributor and process it as normal.

### Scenario 02

[image: Command and event scenario]

In scenario two it's pretty much the same. The PublishCommand is sent to Endpoint3@Cluster01. It 
picks one of the ready Endpoint3s, in this case Endpoint3@ServicesBox02, and gives it the command.
ServiceBox02 processes the message and publishes the SomeEvent to Endpoint01@Cluster01 and 
Endpoint02@Cluster01. These are picked up by the distributor and in this case sent to 
Endpoint1@ServiceBox01 and Endpoint2@ServiceBoxN.

Notice how the messages ALWAYS flow THROUGH the distributor and the queues on Cluster01. This is
actual load balancing of MSMQ.

**Config for app server** changes to makes sure the commands go through the cluster.

```
<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>

      <add Assembly="Messages" Type="PublisherCommand" Endpoint="Endpoint3@Cluster01" />
      <add Assembly="Messages" Type="Worker1Command" Endpoint="Endpoint1@Cluster01" />
      <add Assembly="Messages" Type="Worker2Command" Endpoint="Endpoint2@Cluster01" />
      <!-- This one is sent locally only -->
      <add Assembly=" Messages" Type="RunCalculationCommand" Endpoint="Dealing" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

**ServicesBox config** changes slightly to make sure subscriptions go through the distributor as well.

```
<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Assembly="Messages" Type="SomeEvent" Endpoint="Endpoint3@Cluster01" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

**No changes for the publisher config.** It doesn't need to point to anything. The subscribers will tell it where to publish.

Comment: janovesk, Thanks for the good answer. I knew this would not be easy, and was aware of the fact we would have to cluster MSMQ, so no surprises there. I have one more query on this, if the app server config has to point to a particular endpoint within a given cluster isn't that again a single point of failure? What happens if that endpoint within the cluster is down?

Comment: You're welcome! The distributor endpoints run as clustered services on the Windows cluster as well, just like DTC and MSMQ. If a distributor endpoint fails it will fail over to the other cluster node and start up there.(And nobody should notice, except the small startup delay of the distributor on the other cluster node). Also remember that the app server only sends to the queue on the cluster, so if the endpoint happens to fail over at that instant the message will be there in the queue when the distributor endpoint is back up on the other node.